# Keep rows in dataframe where values are present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2:

| Transport | City | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Paris | red |
| Car | London | white |
| Bike | Paris | red |
| Car | New York | blue |

| Color |
| --- |
| red |
| blue |
| blue |

They are not the same length.

I want to make a new dataframe based on the first one, where I only keep the row, if the color is also present in the second dataframe, such that the output would be:

| Transport | City | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Paris | red |
| Bike | Paris | red |
| Car | New York | Blue |

Is there a way to do that? I want to write something like:

```
df1[df1.Color.isin(df2.Color)]
```

But it does not seem to work.

edit: I think the issue is that the data type in the first dataframe is str and not in the second.

Comment: Both the color and the city combination should be the same? e.g. Paris & Blue should also be in the desired output?

Comment: Yes they should match so the row stays intact if that makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  You should use `df2.Color.unique()` for performance sake, but it should work either way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with a merge after dropping duplicates to avoid cartesian product:

```
df_1.merge(df_2.drop_duplicates(),left_on=['City','Color'],right_on=['City','Color'])
```

Outputting:

```
  Transport      City Color
0       Car     Paris   red
1      Bike     Paris   red
2       Car  New York  blue
```

Answer (score 1):

If both should match you need to merge and then filter out the nulls:

```
df1 = df1.merge(right=df2.drop_duplicates(), on=['City','Color'], how='left')
df1.dropna(subset=['Transport'], inplace = True)
```

Let me know if this works for you